# What size wire to use from house to wood shop?

Tags: electrical, wire

What type/size of wire should I use for running power from the 200Amp service panel at my house to a subpanel at my wood shop? The length of the run is 300 feet. I need 220V service at the shop and would like to run a 70 amp circuit. I would like the wire to be direct burial, +/- 2 ft deep. Voltage drop limit is 3%.

I was told that I could use #1 THHN copper wire in conduit OR aluminum wire rated for a 100 amp circuit, but was not given a gauge/type of aluminum wire.

What size wire should I use?

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/41972/33), [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/49705/33), and [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/29077/33) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [good calculator](http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm) that will answer your question.

It says #1 copper, 2/0 for aluminum.